# SQL Cursor returning many number of tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql stored proc where I use a cursor that contains a set of id's from a select statement and I use these id's going over one by one using the cursor to get values into other variables and use those variables to do sql joins .My problem is when I execute this I get many tables returned whereas I need just one table returned.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON


declare @BSVal as int
declare @GSVal as int

declare @mID as int
declare @qID as int

DECLARE M_Cursor cursor for

select 
ms.MID,ms.QID
from  vM As ms join QS as qs
ON ms.QSID=qs.QIDjoin 
Mar as mar on mar.MarID=qs.MarID
where (ms.Cid='Web')

open M_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM M_Cursor 
INTO @mID, @qID


--Get values
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @BSVal= (select top 1 SCID from vSC where (EnID in 
(select EnID from En where EnName='BAIDU')
and QTID=1 and MID=@mIDand QSID=@qID)order by ITime desc); 
set @GSVal= (select top 1 SCID from vSC where ( EnID in 
(select EnID from En where EnName='GRAPHIC') and QTID=1 
and MID=@mIDand QSID=@QSID) order by ITime desc);




select  * from 

vM m 

join vw5TABLE BNDCG on (m.QSid=BNDCG.QID And BNDCG.Position=1) 
join vw5TABLE GNDCG on (m.QSid=GNDCG.QID And GNDCG.Position=1)

where

BNDCG.SCid=@BSVal
and GNDCG.SCid=@GSVal
and BNDCG.QSID=@ qID
and GNDCG.QSID=@ qID
and m.MID=@mID




FETCH NEXT FROM M_Cursor 
   INTO @MID, @QSID


END
CLOSE M_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE M_Cursor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will run a select for each iteration of the cursor, which makes it look like 'many tables'. It sounds like you need to insert the results of that select into a temp table or table variable inside the cursor, then once the cursor is complete, select once from that temp table. I have not gone over your code in detail but I'm guessing a cursor may not be required for this.

Here's a rough sample using a table variable.

```
DECLARE @temptable  TABLE (col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(3), Col3 INT)


insert into @temptable (col1,col2,col3)
select  (col1,col2,col3) from 
vM m 
join vw5TABLE BNDCG on (m.QSid=BNDCG.QID And BNDCG.Position=1) 
join vw5TABLE GNDCG on (m.QSid=GNDCG.QID And GNDCG.Position=1)
where
BNDCG.SCid=@BSVal
and GNDCG.SCid=@GSVal
and BNDCG.QSID=@ qID
and GNDCG.QSID=@ qID
and m.MID=@mID

....
..

DEALLOCATE M_Cursor;

SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM @temptable
```

Comment: Thanks ! sounds correct ,I'll implement a temp table as suggested by you.

Comment: One more question on related note ,the query returns null rows as well how to avoid getting the null rows in the ouput ,is the only way to add IS NOT NULL for each condition--Thanks

Comment: Don't mind the above question ,after using the temp table approach no null rows were returned.